# How to convert my object date to strftime with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I've a data stored in my database in the column `date`. If I print my data, I have `2017-05-16 00:00:00`.

Now, I would like (in French), 16 mai 2017. I heard about sftrtime, but I can not seem to use it. Can you help me please ?

I tried `strftime($article->date)` and `strftime('%A %d %B', $article->date)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr');
return \Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->date)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

// mardi 16 mai 2017
```

Comment: I try your method, but the date returned is in English. In my model Article, I create a method `getDateForHuman()` and I try this `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr');` `return Carbon::parse($this->date)->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');`. In my view, I try `$article->getDateForHuman()`. Result is in English. You are why?

Comment: You need to verify if you have the locale installed in your server.

Answer (score 1):

If `date` is in the [`$dates`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) array, then it's a Carbon instance, so you can do this:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');
$date->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y');
```

If not, just use `parse()` method to parse string to get Carbon instance and then use `formatLocalized()`

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: I try your method, but the date returned is in English. In my model Article, I create a method `getDateForHuman()` and I try this `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');` `return Carbon::parse($this->date)->formatLocalized('%d %B %Y');`. In my view, I try `$article->getDateForHuman()`. Result is in English. You are why?

Answer (score 0):

it is always good idea to consult official manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

sample code for french:

```
$timestamp = gmmktime(0,0,0,5,16,2017);
if (!setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')) die('Cannot set locale');
echo strftime('%e %B %Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Yes… but I don't have a timestamp but a field type "date" in my database

Comment: @Jeremy then you can google how to parse string into timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'IND');
$tanggal = date_create($item->tanggal_masuk);
$tgl =  \Carbon\Carbon::parse($tanggal)->formatLocalized('%d-%m-%Y');
echo $tgl;
```